# Starting a sentence with “hitherto” in context of writing a biography?

Tags: word-choice

Would it be okay to start a sentence about my experience with something like this:

> Hitherto I have worked for XYZ companies …

I have checked Google News and found the word used mainly in the middle of sentences like:

> ... hitherto unknown ...
>   ... hitherto unrecorded ...
>   ... hitherto unbeaten ...
>   ... hitherto absent ...
>   ... hitherto dilapidated ...

If this does not fit inm I will use *to date.*

Comment: You really do not need an introductory word at all. You can simply begin with, "I have worked for XYZ," etc. Both "hitherto" and "to date" can be assumed by your reader.

Comment: @MarkHubbard I see. What if this para falls in the middle of bio I am writing? Leaving aside the assumption, please tell if this will make sense or not.

Comment: In the middle of a bio, I would go with "To date," etc. "Hitherto" can seem a bit fussy, in my opinion.

Comment: Don't use *hitherto*. Ever. Not only do most native speakers not know what it means,  it also sounds old-fashioned  and some uses of it are archaic (and the ones that aren't are probably headed that way).

Comment: Wherefore and hither now, we are gathered on this solemn occasion...

Comment: @Drew - "Why and to this place now"? Does that come from something? I can't seem to find that exact phrase anywhere.

Comment: @Spratty: Just kidding.

Comment: @Drew - ah, that explains it. I thought I was about to learn something profound! :-)